# How to make all the nodes of a graph in graphviz start at same horizontal level ?

Tags: graphviz, skip-lists

I am trying to display a skiplist data structure in graphviz. How do I make all the nodes of the graph to start off at the same horizontal height instead of random node positions ?

Comment: There is no generic method to position nodes, that I am aware of. But If you can paste the screenshot of how your current figure looks like, and link to the dot fule, we can do a little bit of tweaking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to control node placement in graphviz (i.e. avoid edge crossings)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476575/how-to-control-node-placement-in-graphviz-i-e-avoid-edge-crossings)